# When writing negative unit tests, should one test for "environmental response"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, methodology

Imagine I have simple "immutable at it's best" structure class:

```
class Foobar(object):
    __slots__ = ('_foo', '_bar')

    def __init__(self, *, foo, bar):
        self._foo = foo
        self._bar = bar

    foo = property(lambda self: self._foo)
    bar = property(lambda self: self._bar)

    def woof(self):
        return self._foo + self._bar
```

I can think of these obvious tests to test this class:

- `Foobar(foo=-20, bar=62).foo == -20`
- `Foobar(foo=-20, bar=62).bar == 62`
- `Foobar(foo=-20, bar=62).woof() == 42`
- `Foobar(foo=-20, bar=62).foo = 314` should throw `AttributeError`
- `Foobar(foo=-20, bar=62).bar = 314` should throw `AttributeError`

However, these tests only account for happy cases. But when it comes down to testing for non-success, I'm stuck:

1. Should I test that constructor throws on extraneous arguments? Throws on positional arguments? Throws on missing keyword arguments?
2. Should I test that instance can't be assigned additional attributes?
3. Should I test that `woof()` does not accept arguments?
4. Should I bruteforce through cartesian product of some large list of contextually inappropriate types (integers, floats, lists, tuples, dicts, Nones, sets, frozensets, bytes, strings, regexes, slices, frames, functions, bound methods and so on) and try each possible combination of `foo` and `bar`? If I should, how to pick types into that set?

By "environmental response" I mean implicit work runtime does to the code. It's not my code directly throwing `TypeError` when given insufficient/extraneous arguments, but runtime checks, based on my code.

By bruteforcing through cartesian product of list of types I mean trying following:

```
Foobar(foo=0,         bar=0        ).woof()
Foobar(foo=0,         bar=None     ).woof()
Foobar(foo=0,         bar=lambda: 0).woof()
Foobar(foo=0,         bar=()       ).woof()
Foobar(foo=0,         bar=(10, )   ).woof()
Foobar(foo=0,         bar=""       ).woof()
Foobar(foo=0,         bar="test"   ).woof()
Foobar(foo=0,         bar=True     ).woof()
...
Foobar(foo=None,      bar=0        ).woof()
Foobar(foo=None,      bar=None     ).woof()
Foobar(foo=None,      bar=lambda: 0).woof()
Foobar(foo=None,      bar=()       ).woof()
Foobar(foo=None,      bar=(10, )   ).woof()
Foobar(foo=None,      bar=""       ).woof()
Foobar(foo=None,      bar="test"   ).woof()
Foobar(foo=None,      bar=True     ).woof()
...
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar=0        ).woof()
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar=None     ).woof()
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar=lambda: 0).woof()
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar=()       ).woof()
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar=(10, )   ).woof()
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar=""       ).woof()
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar="test"   ).woof()
Foobar(foo=lambda: 0, bar=True     ).woof()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd say no. One of Python's mottos is "we're all responsible users here".

The only time you should test for out-of-specs usage is if you can make a strong case for users to expect that functionality to work. And in that case you should also consider just implementing that behaviour - it's expected after all.

Comment: Okay, that might count for feeding class with wrong types, because that would be entirely that consenting adult's fail, so `#4` is out. But what with `#1` and `#2`? According to test-driven methodologies, every line of code has to be tested before it's written. So in order to "have right" to write list of arguments to constructor, as well as to "have right" to limit `__slots__`, _something_ has to be tested before — but what exactly?